# webSphere v8 concurrency issue - Startup hangs during message driven activation

Tags: jvm, ibm-mq, websphere-7, websphere-8, mq

I got concurrency issue while starting the JVM due to a particular app. Start-up hangs during message driven activation. I got this URL 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ68236 (the same error I got for myself as mentioned in URL) and fixed as a local solution.  Want to fix this issue as a permanent solution but got to know the 'ConnectionConcurrency' has been removed from v7+. Can anyone please suggest me how to fix this as a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

The permanent solution **is** as documented in the APAR closing words; that is, a configuration change to set the value of the MQ Resource Adapter property "ConnectionConcurrency" to the value 1 at ***Cell*** scope (if using WebSphere Application Server). There is no change code for the WebSphere MQ v7.0.1 RA (shipped in WAS v7.0 or 8.0) for this issue.

Note: It does not matter what scope your Activation Specifications are actually defined at (whether that be Cell, Node or Server), the value of "ConnectionConcurrency" is always taken from the RA defined at Cell scope.

From the WebSphere MQ v7.1 Resource Adapter (shipped in WAS v8.5), the "ConnectionConcurrency" attribute is always set to the value 1 to avoid the deadlock issue described by APAR IZ68236.

Comment: I have WAS 8 and by default the  ConnectionConcurrency was set as 5 . I just selected the scope as ws8cell and then changed it to 1 . Is it  good? Let me know if need to check something more.